# Hyperledger IROHA get_acc_ast_tx in CLI mode dont work

Tags: hyperledger-iroha

I just finished the pluralsigt course and completed the tutorial of the official project documentation without problems, but nevertheless using the CLI I could not use the functions get_acc_ast_tx, get_acc_tx, I checked that the peer keys and the configuration files and correspond to genesis file, where admin@test is allowed to use these functions and I get:

> [2019-12-08 04: 55: 57.883070400] [E] [CLI/ResponseHandler/Query]: Query is stateless invalid.

The genesis file I use is the initial one of the git repository:

```
{
"blockV1": {
    "payload": {
        "transactions": [{
            "payload": {
                "reducedPayload": {
                    "commands": [{
                        "addPeer": {
                            "peer": {
                                "address": "127.0.0.1:10001",
                                "peerKey": "bddd58404d1315e0eb27902c5d7c8eb0602c16238f005773df406bc191308929"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createRole": {
                            "roleName": "admin",
                            "permissions": ["can_add_peer", "can_add_signatory", "can_create_account", "can_create_domain", "can_get_all_acc_ast", "can_get_all_acc_ast_txs", "can_get_all_acc_detail", "can_get_all_acc_txs", "can_get_all_accounts", "can_get_all_signatories", "can_get_all_txs", "can_get_blocks", "can_get_roles", "can_read_assets", "can_remove_signatory", "can_set_quorum"]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createRole": {
                            "roleName": "user",
                            "permissions": ["can_add_signatory", "can_get_my_acc_ast", "can_get_my_acc_ast_txs", "can_get_my_acc_detail", "can_get_my_acc_txs", "can_get_my_account", "can_get_my_signatories", "can_get_my_txs", "can_grant_can_add_my_signatory", "can_grant_can_remove_my_signatory", "can_grant_can_set_my_account_detail", "can_grant_can_set_my_quorum", "can_grant_can_transfer_my_assets", "can_receive", "can_remove_signatory", "can_set_quorum", "can_transfer"]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createRole": {
                            "roleName": "money_creator",
                            "permissions": ["can_add_asset_qty", "can_create_asset", "can_receive", "can_transfer"]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createDomain": {
                            "domainId": "test",
                            "defaultRole": "user"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createAsset": {
                            "assetName": "coin",
                            "domainId": "test",
                            "precision": 2
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createAccount": {
                            "accountName": "admin",
                            "domainId": "test",
                            "publicKey": "313a07e6384776ed95447710d15e59148473ccfc052a681317a72a69f2a49910"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "createAccount": {
                            "accountName": "test",
                            "domainId": "test",
                            "publicKey": "716fe505f69f18511a1b083915aa9ff73ef36e6688199f3959750db38b8f4bfc"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "appendRole": {
                            "accountId": "admin@test",
                            "roleName": "admin"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "appendRole": {
                            "accountId": "admin@test",
                            "roleName": "money_creator"
                        }
                    }],
                    "quorum": 1
                }
            }
        }],
        "txNumber": 1,
        "height": "1",
        "prevBlockHash": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
}
```

}

I use the hyperledger image of docker, in MAC OS CATALINA.

I followed the tutorial according to this manual: https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build/index.html

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: These commands work well with the api and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CLI is rather outdated – we are working on new solution for it, but meanwhile it is better to use one of the SDKs available – for [Java](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-java), [Python](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-python), [JS](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-javascript) or [iOS](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-ios) (if you prefer mobile development).
All of them contain examples, so it should not be too tricky to use those. Although, if you encounter any issues, please contact us using one of the chats [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha#need-help).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to outdated cli. A newer version that is [developed](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-tui-client) will replace it, but is not yet ready.

The exact problem is that there was pagination metadata added for these queries in iroha, but the cli was not updated to set it properly. Protobuf transport allows cli to send a query without some fields that were added later, but iroha refuses to handle it.

You can use one of client libraries that are always kept up to date: https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/develop/libraries.html.